# Could not find Party for Anonymous(DLC2iDbLTxfABXk2UgFJzej8RbX6hUQuCjYBDJATYjYAJW) ERROR in corda accounts

Tags: corda

I am getting this error in one of the flows while using accounts in my cordapp, net.corda.core.CordaRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find Party for Anonymous(DLBBYFJYhpPQXEMcTZtuzkg8ixptu92L3dqiN4boD1o2FN)
This error comes at the Finality Flow line

Here is error log

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find Party for Anonymous(DLKiQpwdw3E7CewLhUatjRpKvCMkHDhEoEYXfAUrp33z7)
    at net.corda.core.identity.IdentityUtils.groupAbstractPartyByWellKnownParty(IdentityUtils.kt:47) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.identity.IdentityUtils.groupAbstractPartyByWellKnownParty(IdentityUtils.kt:63) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.extractExternalParticipants(FinalityFlow.kt:224) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:134) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:39) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:330) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:326) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at com.template.flows.LoanTransferFlow.call(LoanTransferFlow.java:129) ~[?:?]
    at com.template.flows.LoanTransferFlow.call(LoanTransferFlow.java:29) ~[?:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:270) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:46) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
```

the flow takes in a input state & 3 output state.

Here is the flow code:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public class LoanTransferFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {

    final AccountInfo borrower;
    final AccountInfo lender;
    UniqueIdentifier loanId = null;
    StateAndRef<InfoState> inputBorrowerState = null;
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoanTransferFlow.class);


    public LoanTransferFlow(AccountInfo borrower, AccountInfo lender, UniqueIdentifier loanId, StateAndRef<InfoState> inputBorrowerState) {
        this.borrower = borrower;
        this.lender = lender;
        this.loanId = loanId;
        this.inputBorrowerState = inputBorrowerState;
    }

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
        final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
        List<StateAndRef<InfoState>> matchingLenderStates = null;

        StateAndRef<InfoState> inputInfoLenderState = null;
        StateAndRef<LoanState> inputLoanState = null;


//
//        PublicKey myKey = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(lender.getHost(), lender.getIdentifier().getId())).getOwningKey();
//        PublicKey borrowerKey = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(borrower.getHost(), borrower.getIdentifier().getId())).getOwningKey();

        try {

            Vault.Page<InfoState> lenderStateresults = (Vault.Page<InfoState>) subFlow(new CheckAccountInfoFlow(lender.getName()));
            matchingLenderStates = lenderStateresults.getStates();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FlowException(e);

        }
        if ((matchingLenderStates == null) || (matchingLenderStates.isEmpty())) {
            throw new FlowException("No Initial Borrower State Exists");
        } else {
            inputInfoLenderState = matchingLenderStates.get(matchingLenderStates.size() - 1);
        }

        QueryCriteria criteriaForLoanVault = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(
                null,
                ImmutableList.of(loanId),
                Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED,
                null);
        List<StateAndRef<LoanState>> matchingLoanStates = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(LoanState.class, criteriaForLoanVault).getStates();
        if ((matchingLoanStates == null) || (matchingLoanStates.isEmpty())) {
            throw new FlowException("No Initial Loan State Exists");
        } else {
            inputLoanState = matchingLoanStates.get(0);
        }

        subFlow(new ShareStateAndSyncAccounts(inputLoanState, borrower.getHost()));

        subFlow(new ShareStateAndSyncAccounts(inputLoanState, lender.getHost()));

        PublicKey myKey = inputLoanState.getState().getData().getLender();
        PublicKey borrowerKey = inputLoanState.getState().getData().getBorrower();

        logger.info("inputState" + inputLoanState.getState().getData().getBorrower() + inputLoanState.getState().getData().getLender());
        logger.info("mykey" + myKey);
        logger.info("borrowerKey" + borrowerKey);

        float updatedBorrowerCreditscore = inputLoanState.getState().getData().getCreditScore() - 15;
        float updatedLenderCreditscore = inputInfoLenderState.getState().getData().getCreditScore() + 30;
        float amount = inputLoanState.getState().getData().getAmount();
        float borrowerBalance = inputBorrowerState.getState().getData().getBalance();
        float lenderBalance = inputInfoLenderState.getState().getData().getBalance();
        if (amount > lenderBalance) {
            throw new FlowException("Insufficient Lender Balance");
        }
        float updatedBorrowerBalance = borrowerBalance + amount;
        float updatedLenderBalance = lenderBalance - amount;

        final Command<LendingContract.Commands.Transfer> command = new Command<LendingContract.Commands.Transfer>(new LendingContract.Commands.Transfer(), Arrays.asList(myKey, borrowerKey));

        LoanState outputLoanState = new LoanState(borrowerKey, myKey, amount, updatedBorrowerCreditscore, "approved", new UniqueIdentifier());
        logger.info("outputState" + outputLoanState.getLender() + outputLoanState.getBorrower());

        InfoState outputBorrowerState = new InfoState(new AnonymousParty(borrowerKey), updatedBorrowerCreditscore, updatedBorrowerBalance, new UniqueIdentifier());

        InfoState outputLenderState = new InfoState(new AnonymousParty(myKey), updatedLenderCreditscore, updatedLenderBalance, new UniqueIdentifier());

        TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
        txBuilder.addInputState(inputLoanState);
        txBuilder.addCommand(command);
        txBuilder.addOutputState(outputBorrowerState, LendingContract.ID);
        txBuilder.addOutputState(outputLenderState, LendingContract.ID);
        txBuilder.addOutputState(outputLoanState, LendingContract.ID);
        txBuilder.verify(getServiceHub());

        SignedTransaction signedInitialTransaction = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, Arrays.asList(getOurIdentity().getOwningKey(), myKey));

        FlowSession counterPartySession = initiateFlow(borrower.getHost());

        List<? extends TransactionSignature> accountToMoveToSignature = subFlow(new CollectSignatureFlow(signedInitialTransaction, counterPartySession, borrowerKey));

        SignedTransaction fullySignedTx = signedInitialTransaction.withAdditionalSignature(accountToMoveToSignature.get(0));

        return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx));
```

Gone into the source code, error seems to be coming from this --->

```
@Throws(IllegalArgumentException::class)
fun groupAbstractPartyByWellKnownParty(serviceHub: ServiceHub, parties: Collection<AbstractParty>, ignoreUnrecognisedParties: Boolean): Map<Party, List<AbstractParty>> {
    val partyToPublicKey: Iterable<Pair<Party, AbstractParty>> = parties.mapNotNull {
        (serviceHub.identityService.wellKnownPartyFromAnonymous(it) ?: if (ignoreUnrecognisedParties) return@mapNotNull null else throw IllegalArgumentException("Could not find Party for $it")) to it
    }
    return partyToPublicKey.toMultiMap()
}
```

I have a similar flow without an input state that is working.

State Class:

```
private PublicKey borrower;
private PublicKey lender;
private float amount;
private float creditScore;
private String status;
private final UniqueIdentifier linearId;
```

**FYI I have used PublicKey Data Type as well for borrower & lender in this state**

**FYI The flow works fine without using input states**
Account creation flow

```
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): AccountInfo {
        //Create a new account
        try {
            val existingAccount = accountService.accountInfo(name = acctName)
            if (existingAccount.size >= 1) {
                throw FlowException("Account Already Exists")
            }
            val newAccount = accountService.createAccount(name = acctName).toCompletableFuture().getOrThrow()
            val acct = newAccount.state.data
            return acct
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw FlowException(e)
        }
    }
```

Account sharing flow

```
   @Suspendable
    override fun call(): Boolean {

        //Create a new account
        val AllmyAccounts = accountService.ourAccounts()
        val SharedAccount = AllmyAccounts.single { it.state.data.name == acctNameShared }.state.data.identifier.id
        accountService.shareAccountInfoWithParty(SharedAccount,shareTo)
        return true
```

}

**FYI - There are two accounts both on different nodes**

Adding the input state flow as well.

```
public LoanRequestFlow(AccountInfo borrower, AccountInfo lender, float amount) {
    this.borrower = borrower;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.lender = lender;
}

private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker();

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoanRequestFlow.class);


@Override
public ProgressTracker getProgressTracker() {
    return progressTracker;
}

@Suspendable
@Override
public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
    final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
    List<StateAndRef<InfoState>> matchingBorrowerStates = null;

    StateAndRef<InfoState> inputInfoBorrowerState = null;

    PublicKey myKey = subFlow(new NewKeyForAccount(borrower.getIdentifier().getId())).getOwningKey();
    PublicKey lenderKey = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(lender)).getOwningKey();

    try {

        Vault.Page<InfoState> borrowerStateresults = (Vault.Page<InfoState>) subFlow(new CheckAccountInfoFlow(borrower.getName()));
        matchingBorrowerStates = borrowerStateresults.getStates();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FlowException(e);

    }
    if ((matchingBorrowerStates == null) || (matchingBorrowerStates.isEmpty())) {
        throw new FlowException("No Initial Borrower State Exists");
    } else {
        inputInfoBorrowerState = matchingBorrowerStates.get(matchingBorrowerStates.size() - 1);
    }


    final Command<LendingContract.Commands.Request> command = new Command<LendingContract.Commands.Request>(new LendingContract.Commands.Request(), Arrays.asList(myKey, lenderKey));

    LoanState loanOutputState = new LoanState(myKey, lenderKey, amount, inputInfoBorrowerState.getState().getData().getCreditScore(), "pending", new UniqueIdentifier());

    TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
    txBuilder.addCommand(command);
    txBuilder.addOutputState(loanOutputState, LendingContract.ID);
    txBuilder.verify(getServiceHub());

    SignedTransaction signedInitialTransaction = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, Arrays.asList(getOurIdentity().getOwningKey(), myKey));

    FlowSession counterPartySession = initiateFlow(lender.getHost());

    List<? extends TransactionSignature> accountToMoveToSignature = subFlow(new CollectSignatureFlow(signedInitialTransaction, counterPartySession, lenderKey));

    SignedTransaction fullySignedTx = signedInitialTransaction.withAdditionalSignature(accountToMoveToSignature.get(0));

    return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx));
```

Comment: Make sure you are using Corda 4.3.

Comment: Yup, using it..

Comment: Are the accounts on the same node or different nodes? If they are on different nodes, have you shared the accounts with each node?

Comment: Yes shared the accounts, there is a similar flow to this that works on difference is that doesn't consume a input state

Comment: Viraz, there's too much going on in your flow; it would be hard to find out what's causing the error.

Comment: I recommend that you run your node in debug mode and put break points inside your flow to see where the error is happening.

Comment: https://docs.corda.net/node-commandline.html#enabling-remote-debugging

Comment: The error is in the finality flow line, when I checked the logs

Comment: You are using the deprecated version of FinalityFlow.

Comment: Use this version: `return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedTx, Collections.emptyList()));`

Comment: Also please confirm that inside your root `build.gradle` you are using the latest accounts and confidential identities versions. `accounts_release_version = '1.0'`, `confidential_id_release_version = "1.0"`

Comment: buildscript {
    ext {
        corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
        accounts_release_version = '1.0-RC04'
        accounts_release_group = 'com.r3.corda.lib.accounts'
        confidential_id_release_group = "com.r3.corda.lib.ci"
        confidential_id_release_version = "1.0-RC03"

Comment: Try this: `PublicKey myKey = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(lender)).getOwningKey();`. This flow handles both cases when the account is hosted on the initiating node or on a different node.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get this error is because the Finality flow is looking at your output states and input states and retrieving the participants from them.

It then tries to resolve those participants to parties via the PublicKeys.

If the node hasn't seen those Public Keys before the error you see will be thrown.

Since you have only fragments of code in the question, it isn't very clear where you are causing the issue.

However, the following example will replicate the issue:

```
public class SaveLoanFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
  private AnonymousParty borrower;
  private AnonymousParty lender;
  private float amount;
  private float creditScore;

  public SaveLoanFlow(AnonymousParty borrower, AnonymousParty lender, float amount, float creditScore) {
    this.borrower = borrower;
    this.lender = lender;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.creditScore = creditScore;
  }

  @Suspendable
  @Override
  public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
    final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
    List<PublicKey> signingPubKeys = Arrays.asList(getOurIdentity().getOwningKey());
    TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
    LoanState loanState = new LoanState(borrower, lender, amount, creditScore, "NEW", new UniqueIdentifier());
    txBuilder.addOutputState(loanState);
    txBuilder.addCommand(new LendingContract.Commands.Transfer(), signingPubKeys);

    SignedTransaction signedInitialTransaction = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, signingPubKeys);

    return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedInitialTransaction));
  }
}


public class LendingContract implements Contract {

  public static final Party ID = null;

  @Override
  public void verify(@NotNull LedgerTransaction tx) throws IllegalArgumentException {

  }

  /**
   * This contract only implements one command, Transfer.
   */
  public interface Commands extends CommandData {
    class Transfer implements Commands {}
  }
}

@BelongsToContract(LendingContract.class)
public class LoanState implements LinearState {
  private AnonymousParty borrower;
  private AnonymousParty lender;
  private float amount;
  private float creditScore;
  private String status;
  private UniqueIdentifier linearId;

  public LoanState(AnonymousParty borrower, AnonymousParty lender, float amount, float creditScore, String status, UniqueIdentifier linearId) {
    this.borrower = borrower;
    this.lender = lender;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.creditScore = creditScore;
    this.status = status;
    this.linearId = linearId;
  }

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
    return ImmutableList.of(borrower, lender);
  }

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public UniqueIdentifier getLinearId() {
    return linearId;
  }

//
//other getters/setters
//
 }
```

If you run this flow in a test (kotlin just because I was testing this in an existing project) you will get the error:

```
@Test
fun `Find party`() {
    val borrowerAccountService = borrowerNode.services.cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService::class.java)
    val lenderAccountService = lenderNode.services.cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService::class.java)

    val borrowerAccount = borrowerAccountService.createAccount("Borrower-Account").getOrThrow().state.data
    val lenderAccount = lenderAccountService.createAccount("Lender-Account").getOrThrow().state.data
    network.runNetwork()

    borrowerAccountService.shareAccountInfoWithParty(borrowerAccount.identifier.id, lenderNode.info.legalIdentities[0])
    lenderAccountService.shareAccountInfoWithParty(lenderAccount.identifier.id, borrowerNode.info.legalIdentities[0])
    network.runNetwork()

    val borrowerPartyFuture = borrowerNode.startFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(borrowerAccount))
    val lenderPartyFuture = lenderNode.startFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(lenderAccount))
    network.runNetwork()
    val borrowerParty = borrowerPartyFuture.getOrThrow()
    val lenderParty = lenderPartyFuture.getOrThrow()

    val newLoanFuture = lenderNode.startFlow(SaveLoanFlow(borrowerParty, lenderParty, 2F, 4F))
    network.runNetwork()

    val savedLoan = newLoanFuture.getOrThrow()
    Assert.notEmpty(savedLoan.tx.outputStates)
}
}
```

However, if you change these 2 lines:

```
    val borrowerPartyFuture = borrowerNode.startFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(borrowerAccount))
    val lenderPartyFuture = lenderNode.startFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(lenderAccount))
```

So that the keys are requested from the same node the flow will run and the test will pass.

```
    val borrowerPartyFuture = lenderNode.startFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(borrowerAccount))
    val lenderPartyFuture = lenderNode.startFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(lenderAccount))
```

The reason is that now the lender is aware of the keys for both accounts.

So somewhere in the code that you haven't shown you have a similar issue in that the account keys are not available on both nodes.

It looks like you run another flow before the one you posted in the question because you do a vault lookup and use it as an input state.

One of the keys from the saved state probably don't exist on one of the nodes.

For (unforeseen?) design reasons, when you save the state in a flow the generated keys are not saved and you have to run an extra flow to make sure all the generated keys are synchronised.

You can do this as a subflow at the end of your not shown flow and it might fix the problem.

```
//If you don't do this you can't lookup accounts by PublicKey on the other host
subFlow(ShareStateAndSyncAccounts(state, lenderAccount.state.data.host))
```

Track [this issue](https://github.com/corda/accounts/issues/65) for further info.

Comment: Thanks @opticyclic, yeah I do a a vault query for the account on a state which has only one account, but I am genarting new keys in a previous flow which works without the input state, so what are you suggesting I should do here.?

Comment: earlier i was sharing one account with one node but now i shared the counter account with another node, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: did this (ShareStateAndSyncAccounts) in the flow with both accounts, but still didn't work. Same error

Comment: You say that you are doing Share StateAndSyncAccounts yet the new code you posted clearly shows that you aren't. I would advise copying the code from this answer to your project, running the test to see the error then making the change to see the fix work. You can then see where it applies to your code. Creating a demo project on GitHub that replicates the issue would also make it easier to help you.

Comment: You haven't seen the flow code then look 
 subFlow(new ShareStateAndSyncAccounts(inputLoanState, borrower.getHost()));

        subFlow(new ShareStateAndSyncAccounts(inputLoanState, lender.getHost()));

Comment: Hey @opticyclic , instead of replicating the issue can we get some sample code reference so that we get a clear idea as what needs to be followed to tackle this issue ?
I have same issue " one node has 1 party vault and 1 account, another node has 1 party vault, i have a state shared between both node with account being observer . I am trying to update this state, using addInputState and addOutputState in txBuilder, i get signatures from both parties but Finality flow breaks with error - could not find party for Anonymous(xxxx)". Your explanation is somewhat understood but need reference.

Comment: The explanation is good. While building up the txn, we sometimes create new keys for local accounts from local nodes and sometimes request keys for foreign accounts from foreign nodes. And then when we let the state propagate to new hosts/participants they will not have the mappings between these newly created keys and accountInfos (to find out hosts). And thus while perform a txn on the same state from another host we get this. As told in the solution is the sync the accounts at the end of the flow with all the hosts involved using ShareStateAndSyncAccounts