# Can we modify the Participants list of a corda state while evolving it?

Tags: corda

I made a Corda project in which I have a policy state with one sender and two receivers. I have three nodes seller, Insurance Company and LSP. I created a new PolicyState from an account on Seller's node and sent it to the accounts on Insurance Company and the LSP using the PolicyCreationFlow. This flow worked fine. But When I tried to update a field of this state from the Insurance Company's terminal then it is not working and generating an exception. This means When I am creating the Policy State then the sender is the Seller node and When I am updating the Policy state then the sender is the Insurance Company and the receivers are the rest of the two nodes.

The code for the policy state is as follows:

```
@BelongsToContract(PolicyContract.class)
public class PolicyState implements LinearState  {

    //private variables
    private final UniqueIdentifier linearID;

    private final String sellerID;
    private final String policyID ;
    private final String insurerID;
    private final int policyNo;
    private final double faceValue;
    private final double deathBenefits;
    private final double annualPremium;
    private final double cashSurrenderValue;
    private final String policyStartDate;
    private final boolean isVerfied;
    private List<AnonymousParty> receivingparties;
    private final AnonymousParty policyOwner;
    @Nullable
    private final boolean isValid;

//    private final AnonymousParty inuranceCompany;

    public PolicyState(UniqueIdentifier linearID, String policyID, String sellerID, String insurerID, int policyNo, double faceValue, double deathBenefits, double annualPremium,
                       double cashSurrenderValue, String policyStartDate, AnonymousParty policyOwner, boolean isVerfied, List<AnonymousParty> receivingparties, boolean isValid) {
        this.linearID = linearID;
        this.policyID = policyID;
        this.sellerID = sellerID;
        this.insurerID = insurerID;
        this.policyNo = policyNo;
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
        this.deathBenefits = deathBenefits;
        this.annualPremium = annualPremium;
        this.cashSurrenderValue = cashSurrenderValue;
        this.policyStartDate = policyStartDate;
        this.policyOwner = policyOwner;
        this.isVerfied = isVerfied;
        this.receivingparties = receivingparties;
        this.isValid = isValid;
//        this.inuranceCompany = receivingparties.get(0);
    }

    /////Getters for the Fields
    public String getPolicyID() {
        return policyID;
    }

    public String getSellerID() {
        return sellerID;
    }

    public String getInsurerID() {
        return insurerID;
    }

    public int getPolicyNo() {
        return policyNo;
    }

    public double getFaceValue() {
        return faceValue;
    }

    public double getDeathBenefits() {
        return deathBenefits;
    }

    public double getAnnualPremium() {
        return annualPremium;
    }

    public double getCashSurrenderValue() {
        return cashSurrenderValue;
    }

    public String getPolicyStartDate() {
        return policyStartDate;
    }

    public boolean isVerfied() {
        return isVerfied;
    }

    public AnonymousParty getPolicyOwner() {
        return policyOwner;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public List<AnonymousParty> getReceivingparties() {
        return receivingparties;
    }

    public PolicyState withNewPolicyOwner(AnonymousParty newOwner){
        return new PolicyState(linearID, policyID,sellerID, insurerID, policyNo, faceValue, deathBenefits, annualPremium, cashSurrenderValue, policyStartDate, newOwner, isVerfied, receivingparties, isValid);
    }
    public PolicyState deletePolicy(AnonymousParty policyOwner){
        return new PolicyState(linearID, policyID,sellerID, insurerID, policyNo, faceValue, deathBenefits, annualPremium, cashSurrenderValue, policyStartDate, policyOwner, isVerfied,receivingparties, false);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public UniqueIdentifier getLinearId() {
        return linearID;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
//        return Arrays.asList(policyOwner,inuranceCompany);
        List<AbstractParty> allParts = new ArrayList<>();
        allParts.addAll(receivingparties);
        allParts.add(policyOwner);
        return allParts;

    }
}
```

Code for Policy Creation flow is as follows:

```
@InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    public static class PolicyCreation extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
    private final ProgressTracker.Step GENERATING_TRANSACTION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Generating transaction.");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step ADDING_POLICY = new ProgressTracker.Step("Adding the Policy State to Transaction.");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step VERIFYING_TRANSACTION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Verifying contract constraints.");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step SIGNING_TRANSACTION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Signing transaction with our private key.");
    private final ProgressTracker.Step GATHERING_SIGS = new ProgressTracker.Step("Gathering the counterparty's signature.") {
        @Override
        public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
            return CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker();
        }
    };
    private final ProgressTracker.Step FINALISING_TRANSACTION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.") {
        @Override
        public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
            return FinalityFlow.Companion.tracker();
        }
    };

    private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker(
            GENERATING_TRANSACTION,
            ADDING_POLICY,
            VERIFYING_TRANSACTION,
            SIGNING_TRANSACTION,
            GATHERING_SIGS,
            FINALISING_TRANSACTION
    );


    @Override
    public ProgressTracker getProgressTracker() {
        return progressTracker;
    }

        //PolicyState Fields
        private final String policyID;
        private final String sellerID;
        private final String insurerID;
        private final int policyNo;
        private final double faceValue;
        private final double deathBenefits;
        private final double annualPremium;
        private final double cashSurrenderValue;
        private final String policyStartDate;
        private final String policyOwner;
        private final String insuranceCompany;
        private final String lsp;

        //Constructor for PolicyCreation
        public PolicyCreation(String policyID, String sellerID, String insurerID, int policyNo, double faceValue, double deathBenefits, double annualPremium,
                              double cashSurrenderValue, String policyStartDate, String policyOwner, String insuranceCompany, String lsp) {

            this.policyID = policyID;
            this.sellerID = sellerID;
            this.insurerID = insurerID;
            this.policyNo = policyNo;
            this.faceValue = faceValue;
            this.deathBenefits = deathBenefits;
            this.annualPremium = annualPremium;
            this.cashSurrenderValue = cashSurrenderValue;
            this.policyStartDate = policyStartDate;
            this.policyOwner = policyOwner;
            this.insuranceCompany = insuranceCompany;
            this.lsp = lsp;
        }

        @Suspendable
        @Override
        public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
            AccountService accountService = getServiceHub().cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService.class);

            //Owner Account
            AccountInfo policyOwnerAccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(policyOwner).get(0).getState().getData();
            PublicKey policyOwnerKey = subFlow(new NewKeyForAccount(policyOwnerAccountInfo.getIdentifier().getId())).getOwningKey();

            //Insurance Company Account
            AccountInfo insurerAccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(insuranceCompany).get(0).getState().getData();
            AnonymousParty insuranceCompanyAccount = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(insurerAccountInfo));

            //LSP account
            AccountInfo lspAccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(lsp).get(0).getState().getData();
            AnonymousParty lspAccount = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(lspAccountInfo));

            List<AccountInfo> parties = new ArrayList<>();
            parties.add(insurerAccountInfo);
            parties.add(lspAccountInfo);


            // Step 1. Get a reference to the notary service on our network and our key pair.
            // Note: ongoing work to support multiple notary identities is still in progress.
            final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);

//            UniqueIdentifier policyLinearId = new UniqueIdentifier(policyID);
            final PolicyState output = new PolicyState(new UniqueIdentifier(policyID), policyID, sellerID, insurerID, policyNo, faceValue, deathBenefits, annualPremium, cashSurrenderValue, policyStartDate,new AnonymousParty(policyOwnerKey), false, Arrays.asList(insuranceCompanyAccount,lspAccount), true);

            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(GENERATING_TRANSACTION);
            final TransactionBuilder builder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
            //Adding outputState to the transaction
            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(ADDING_POLICY);
            builder.addOutputState(output, PolicyContract.ID);
            builder.addCommand(new PolicyContract.Commands.Create(), Arrays.asList(policyOwnerKey,insuranceCompanyAccount.getOwningKey(),lspAccount.getOwningKey()));

//          self sign Transaction
            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(SIGNING_TRANSACTION);
            builder.verify(getServiceHub());
            SignedTransaction locallySignedTx = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(builder, Arrays.asList(getOurIdentity().getOwningKey(),policyOwnerKey));


            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(GATHERING_SIGS);
            FlowSession session = initiateFlow(insurerAccountInfo.getHost());
            List<TransactionSignature> accountToMoveToSignature = (List<TransactionSignature>) subFlow(new CollectSignatureFlow(locallySignedTx,
                    session,insuranceCompanyAccount.getOwningKey()));
            SignedTransaction signedByCounterParty = locallySignedTx.withAdditionalSignatures(accountToMoveToSignature);

            FlowSession session1 = initiateFlow(lspAccountInfo.getHost());
            List<TransactionSignature> accountToMoveToSignature1 = (List<TransactionSignature>) subFlow(new CollectSignatureFlow(signedByCounterParty,
                    session1,lspAccount.getOwningKey()));
             signedByCounterParty = signedByCounterParty.withAdditionalSignatures(accountToMoveToSignature1);

            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(FINALISING_TRANSACTION);
            return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedByCounterParty, session,session1));

//            return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedByCounterParty,
//                    Arrays.asList(session).stream().filter(it -> it.getCounterparty() != getOurIdentity()).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        }
    }

    @InitiatedBy(PolicyCreation.class)
    public static class PolicyCreationResponder extends FlowLogic<String> {
        //private variable
        private FlowSession counterpartySession;

        //Constructor
        public PolicyCreationResponder(FlowSession counterpartySession) {
            this.counterpartySession = counterpartySession;
        }

        @Override
        @Suspendable
        public String call() throws FlowException {
            AtomicReference accountMovedTo = new AtomicReference< AccountInfo>();
            SignedTransaction signedTransaction =  subFlow(new SignTransactionFlow(counterpartySession) {
               @Suspendable
                @Override
                protected void checkTransaction(SignedTransaction stx) throws FlowException {
                    // Custom Logic to validate transaction.
                }
            });
            subFlow(new ReceiveFinalityFlow(counterpartySession));
            return "Policy Sent";
        }
    }
```

The code for VerifyPolicyFlow(Updating Flow) is as follow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    public static class VerifyPolicy extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
        private final UniqueIdentifier linearID;
        private final String sender;
//        private final ArrayList<String> receivers;
        private final String receiver1;
        private final String receiver2;
        private final boolean isVerified;



        public VerifyPolicy(UniqueIdentifier linearID, String sender, String receiver1, String receiver2, boolean isVerified) {
            this.linearID = linearID;
            this.sender = sender;
            this.receiver1 = receiver1;
            this.receiver2 = receiver2;
            this.isVerified = isVerified;
        }
//        private ArrayList<AccountInfo> receiversAccountInfo = new ArrayList<>();

        @Suspendable
        @Override
        public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
            AccountService accountService = getServiceHub().cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService.class);

            //Owner Account
            AccountInfo senderAccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(sender).get(0).getState().getData();
            PublicKey senderKey = subFlow(new NewKeyForAccount(senderAccountInfo.getIdentifier().getId())).getOwningKey();

            AccountInfo receiver1AccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(receiver1).get(0).getState().getData();
            AnonymousParty receiver1Account = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(receiver1AccountInfo));

            //LSP account
            AccountInfo receiver2AccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(receiver2).get(0).getState().getData();
            AnonymousParty receiver2Account = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(receiver2AccountInfo));

            List<UUID> listOfLinearIds = new ArrayList<>();
            listOfLinearIds.add(linearID.getId());
            QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, listOfLinearIds);

            // 2. Get a reference to the inputState data that we are going to settle.
            Vault.Page results = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(PolicyState.class, queryCriteria);
            StateAndRef inputStateAndRefToTransfer = (StateAndRef) results.getStates().get(0);
            PolicyState inputStateToTransfer = (PolicyState) inputStateAndRefToTransfer.getState().getData();

            // Step 1. Get a reference to the notary service on our network and our key pair.
            // Note: ongoing work to support multiple notary identities is still in progress.
            final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);

//            UniqueIdentifier policyLinearId = new UniqueIdentifier(policyID);
            final PolicyState output = new PolicyState(inputStateToTransfer.getLinearId(), inputStateToTransfer.getPolicyID(),
                    inputStateToTransfer.getSellerID(), inputStateToTransfer.getInsurerID(), inputStateToTransfer.getPolicyNo(),
                    inputStateToTransfer.getFaceValue(),inputStateToTransfer.getDeathBenefits(), inputStateToTransfer.getAnnualPremium(),
                    inputStateToTransfer.getCashSurrenderValue(), inputStateToTransfer.getPolicyStartDate(),
                    new AnonymousParty(senderKey), isVerified, Arrays.asList(receiver1Account,receiver2Account), true);

            final TransactionBuilder builder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
            //Adding outputState to the transaction

            builder.addInputState(inputStateAndRefToTransfer);
            builder.addOutputState(output, PolicyContract.ID);
            builder.addCommand(new PolicyContract.Commands.Update(), Arrays.asList(senderKey,receiver1Account.getOwningKey(),receiver2Account.getOwningKey()));

            builder.verify(getServiceHub());
            SignedTransaction locallySignedTx = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(builder, Arrays.asList(getOurIdentity().getOwningKey(),senderKey));

            FlowSession session = initiateFlow(receiver1AccountInfo.getHost());
            List<TransactionSignature> accountToMoveToSignature = (List<TransactionSignature>) subFlow(new CollectSignatureFlow(locallySignedTx,
                    session,receiver1Account.getOwningKey()));
            SignedTransaction signedByCounterParty = locallySignedTx.withAdditionalSignatures(accountToMoveToSignature);

            FlowSession session1 = initiateFlow(receiver2AccountInfo.getHost());
            List<TransactionSignature> accountToMoveToSignature1 = (List<TransactionSignature>) subFlow(new CollectSignatureFlow(signedByCounterParty,
                    session1,receiver2Account.getOwningKey()));
            signedByCounterParty = signedByCounterParty.withAdditionalSignatures(accountToMoveToSignature1);

            return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedByCounterParty, session,session1));

//            return null;
        }
    }

    @InitiatedBy(VerifyPolicy.class)
    public static class VerifyPolicyResponder extends FlowLogic<String> {
        //private variable
        private FlowSession counterpartySession;
        //Constructor
        public VerifyPolicyResponder(FlowSession counterpartySession) {
            this.counterpartySession = counterpartySession;
        }

        @Override
        @Suspendable
        public String call() throws FlowException {
            AtomicReference accountMovedTo = new AtomicReference< AccountInfo>();
            SignedTransaction signedTransaction =  subFlow(new SignTransactionFlow(counterpartySession) {
                @Suspendable
                @Override
                protected void checkTransaction(SignedTransaction stx) throws FlowException {
                    // Custom Logic to validate transaction.
                }
            });
            subFlow(new ReceiveFinalityFlow(counterpartySession));
            return "Policy Sent";
            }
        }
```

The logs of the Insurance Company node says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find Party for Anonymous(DLCtNGZXmvmEJCHLNA1GCCwYv39gGJxsgf7MTfytmKgtT4)
    at net.corda.core.identity.IdentityUtils.groupAbstractPartyByWellKnownParty(IdentityUtils.kt:47) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.identity.IdentityUtils.groupAbstractPartyByWellKnownParty(IdentityUtils.kt:63) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.extractExternalParticipants(FinalityFlow.kt:252) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:162) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:43) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:362) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:397) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at com.BLife.flows.VerifyPolicyFlow$VerifyPolicy.call(VerifyPolicyFlow.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at com.BLife.flows.VerifyPolicyFlow$VerifyPolicy.call(VerifyPolicyFlow.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:299) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:66) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
```

logs of the Seller node(which is one of the receivers of the Updating flow) says:

```
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Counter-flow errored
    at Received unexpected counter-flow exception from peer O=InsuranceCompany, L=New York, C=US.() ~[?:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.fillInLocalStackTrace(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:204) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.processEventsUntilFlowIsResumed(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:192) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.suspend(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:506) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.receive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:67) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.receive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:71) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveTransactionFlow.call(ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt:103) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveTransactionFlow.call(ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt:31) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:362) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:397) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveFinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:285) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveFinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:280) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:362) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:397) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at com.BLife.flows.VerifyPolicyFlow$VerifyPolicyResponder.call(VerifyPolicyFlow.java:133) ~[?:?]
    at com.BLife.flows.VerifyPolicyFlow$VerifyPolicyResponder.call(VerifyPolicyFlow.java:113) ~[?:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:299) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:66) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
```

How can I make it correct, Because according to the project requirement Seller will add the Policy on blockchain and the Insurance company will verify the same policy?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this issue occurs because the receiver does not have the `AccountInfo` of the sender. When you create the seller account, you generate also the public key of that account, but other participants don't know the mapping between that key and the X.500 name of the seller node.

You could add this at the end of your PolicyCreation flow:

```
subFlow(ShareStateAndSyncAccounts(state, borrowerAccountInfo.state.data.host))
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/flows/ShareStateWithAccountFlows.kt).

As reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303708/could-not-find-party-for-anonymousdlc2idbltxfabxk2ugfjzej8rbx6huqucjybdjatyjyaj) and [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/issues/65).

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, But I have shared all accounts with ShareAccountInfo.Should I still get the same error ?